# Re-installation of macOS Ventura fails on MacBook Pro 16-inch (Apple M2 Pro)

Tags: macos, macbook, macos-ventura, apple

I am trying to re install my MacOS Ventura on my MacBook Pro 16-inch (Apple M2 Pro) but it fails.

I have erased my hard disk after encountering a problem. I used “Disk Utility” to erase it and formatted it to APFS filesystem.

I enter the recovery options menu by switching my mac off and press power button + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. Then I select options and then select re install.

I then start a dialog and follow the steps and it tells me to wait 14 hours of which I wait. But it finishes earlier, in maybe 6 hours, but when it finishes an error pops up saying an error occurred while preparing installation, this has failed 2 times already.

I don’t know how to resolve this. I cannot take the laptop to an Apple Store at the moment.

Comment: Erasing is fine (when you want to just reinstall) but you should let the installer handle the creation of partitions and format. Very likely that was the problem.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Then that is easy enough to get past while installing. Just choose the proper option to wipe and install and that’s it.